# sl-button is not a known element - Importing css library into Angular

Tags: css, angular, shoelace

I'm simply trying to import the https://shoelace.style/ library for use within an Angular app.

I've tried both their recommended method of adding `style` and `link` elements into the index file, and I've also tried adding their NPM package and then adding the following to my `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/themes/base.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/shoelace.js"
            ],
```

However no matter what I do, whenever I try to use a particular Shoelace component such as `<sl-button>` I get `'sl-button' is not a known element`

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to  your app module
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

Comment: Doing this doesn't provide with autocompletes in vs-code however, how can I enable them too?

Comment: https://shoelace.style/getting-started/usage follow the documentation about vscode

Comment: Shoelace ships with a file called vscode.html-custom-data.json that can be used to describe its components to Visual Studio Code. This enables code completion for Shoelace components (also known as "code hinting" or "IntelliSense"). To enable it, you need to tell VS Code where the file is.

Install Shoelace locally
Create a folder called .vscode at the root of your project
Create a file inside the folder called settings.json
Add the following to the file
{
  "html.customData": ["./node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/vscode.html-custom-data.json"]
}

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to apply the custom elements schema as shown below.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can find more about CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA [here](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA)

Comment: Doing this doesn't provide with autocompletes in vs-code however, how can I enable them too?

Comment: In fact, doing this doesn't actually render anything to my app when I use `<sl-button>` so this method doesn't work

Comment: well this method is mentioned in the official docs.